# Clojure presetting database

Tags: database, clojure, luminus

I just started learning Clojure and made my first web app with a h2 embedded database engine and Luminus framework. I would like to preset a database so when my app runs for the first time it comes with an admin user already in the database.

I added the code to do that in the core.clj main, after (start-app args), but I am certain it is not supposed to go there.

I would be very thankful if somebody could explain it to me where this preset is supposed to go and why. Some good tutorial would also be much appreciated since I google-ed and google-ed but found nothing on this topic.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a good fit for migrations. More info here: http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/migrations.md

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. I thought of that too, but I encrypted the user password using buddy, and I can't encrypt it in the migrations (can I?), so I thought there was a better way.

Comment: @Hachiko93, Typically one would want to persist that data so it didn't need to be re-inserted every time the app is started.  I think h2 is memory only, so I can see why you would want to re-insert every time the app is started.  Is there any particular reason you're not using a persistent db?

Comment: Well not really, this one was in a tutorial, so I started from there. But even with the persistent db I would have to insert an admin at least once, right? Where would I do that then if my app only inserts non-admin users? I would still need some preconfiguration?

Comment: Put a clojure file somewhere.  I like putting things like that in a namespace called `dev` like `myluminusapp.dev.whatever`.  Then run it from the repl or something like that.